# HP ProLiant DL360 G6 won't boot

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, boot, ilo

I have an hp proliant DL360 G6 server that was 1 year stopped.. 
I turned it on last week and it was working just fine. So i left it working during the weekend. 
On Monday when i returned i notice that it was on suspension mode. I tried to bring it back to life but no results.
So i turned it off by pressing the button, when i turned it on again it wont boot and no post. I only gives me a long beep continuosly. I have changed the memorys, processor and fans are runing fine. The internal leds on MB are all green but i have a blinking green led next to the memory slots 1. On front the power button led is green but the health led is blinking red.
Note: I have changed the hard disks when i turned it on the first time one year and it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: I've logged in into ILO and it shows me everything is running ok, but i don't know  exactly what to look for on there!! Any help please.

Comment: Please examine the ILO log and the IML log. The server will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Done that. IML shows me:Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:03
1
System Fans Not Redundant (Location System)
Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:03
1
Fan Failure (Fan 4, Location System)
Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:03
1
System Fans Not Redundant (Location System)
Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:03
1
Fan Failure (Fan 4, Location System)
Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:01
1
System Fans Not Redundant (Location System)
Repaired
Environment
05/14/2015 12:03
05/14/2015 12:01
1

Comment: and ILO log shows me:Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Caution
iLO 2
[NOT SET]
[NOT SET]
1
Power restored to iLO 2.
Informational
iLO 2
05/18/2015 01:07
05/18/2015 01:07
1
Server power removed.
Informational
iLO 2
05/14/2015 05:15
05/14/2015 05:15
1
On-board clock set; was previously [NOT SET]        what am i missing?

Comment: I was now checking the maintenance switch and cleared the NVRAM with no positive results, but i noticed that the S8 is ON. is that ok?

Comment: @Neil: Please *edit* this into your question while using the formatting tools to make it actually readable.

Answer (score 2):

Please examine the ILO log and the IML log. The server will tell you exactly what's wrong.

[image]

---

[image]

---

But really, I wonder if you may have caused another issue while swapping components looking for a solution. If you're seeing an error on a particular DIMM slot, there may actually be a problem with the CPU socket for the processor associated with that memory bank.

**Inspect the LGA socket for bent pins.**

Short of that, there is a ***[very well-known troubleshooting process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NtIt.png)*** for these servers. Try following the decision tree in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NtIt.png) and see if it helps the process.

You can also just call HP directly for help.

Comment: i just started swapping components yesterday (Monday) when i noticed the server was faulty. This means that when entered to this condition i wasn't present. So i think it should be another thing.

Comment: @Neil If you're not using a [troubleshooting method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5NtIt.png) like noted above, I recommend that you call HP for support.

Comment: I used the troubleshooting method with no results. I will contact hp, thanks for your help.

Comment: Call HP for support.